# How to create CSV file with two values for each column name

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv files of the form:

```
$$Name$$  : Aksahy
$$RedID$$ : 81625894
             test_1 test_2  test_3
            ....some extra data.......
Lower_limit   1       4      100    
Upper_limit   2       5      900
```

I want to create a csv file of the form

```
Name    RedID             test_1                      test_2                   test_3
                   Lower_limit Upper_limit  Lower_limit Upper_limit   Lower_limit Upper_limit
Akshay  81625894      1            5           4          5             100         900
Sumit   81625895      3            7           6          9             300         700
```

......

suggest me a way to do this in python.

Comment: It looks like you've already done it.  What's left to do?  Are there multiple files you want to combine?  Is there one file with multiple records?  Or do you simply need to perform that rearrangement?  [BTW, I'm not sure I'd call those csv files.]

Comment: @DSM The input file has some extra data as well. I just posted the data I want. I don't know how can I give 2 values to each column. I have multiple files of the above form and want to combine data  in single csv file

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

lista = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
listb = ["c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d"]
contents = []

with open('example.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    for itema, itemb in zip(lista, listb):
        contents.append("%s%s\n" % (itema, itemb))

    csvfile.write("".join(contents))
```

Comment: The for loop is the only part you need to take note to, I'm sure you can do what you want with it, you could alternatively make a table (looks like you already have one...) and save to csv...

Comment: but I want these two lists as a part of single column in csv file